# How to convert NaN value to 0 inside app.post in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nan

In below code question1 value is coming as `NaN`. I want to convert it to 0 but I am not able to do it using `parseInt`. How can I do this?

```
app.post('/auth/total',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    const {  question1, question2, question3, question4} = req.body;
    let total1 = parseInt(question1) + parseInt(question2) 
    let total2 = parseInt(question3) + parseInt(question4) 
    
    //some code to insert data in db and render the view 

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Use `isNan()`? Although you must investigate why you get `NaN` in the first place

Comment: Should you not investigating why `question1` is not a number?

Comment: @Bib  I am getting NaN because there is a question with radio button as a option and i have a logic by which these question can be disable ... that is why for disable question value is coming as NaN

Comment: Then add a check before you parse that value. Or after you've parsed it and before you add the values.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava please check above coment

Comment: As said by @Andreas .. set the value as 0 when a question is disabled

Comment: @Andreas Why this question got downgraded ... i have done the research before putting the question but some time your brain get freeze when you are doing many logics .... still i think question is valid ... not needed to be downgraded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
let total1 = (parseInt(question1) || 0) + (parseInt(question2) || 0)
```

this will convert any falsy value to 0